# How to choose specific rows in an sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 10 rows, i want to the query to view only one row. For example the 5th row. How can i do that. ROWNUM and LIMIT did not work for me, any help?

if i use rownum clause i get this

```
select * from final_inv  where rownum<=3 
CATEGORY    ITEM    QTY AVG_PRICE
Rice    Lal Quila   50  50
Spices  Chat Masala 1   200
Spices  Bay Leaf    -23 400
```

I want to only view one row of my choice out of 10. How to do that?

Comment: Use the `id` of the record, or create an additional record which you will use as a counter (1, 2, 3...)

Comment: Can you explain why ROWNUM doesn't work for you?

Comment: if i understand you, you are saying i should add a column which represents each row? and if i do that how can i call each specific row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select CATEGORY, ITEM, QTY AVG_PRICE from (
  select CATEGORY, ITEM, QTY AVG_PRICE, ROWNUM RW 
  from final_inv 
) where RW = 5;
```

Comment: sorry i am beginner but what is t.* in line 2?

Comment: @Jarvis "t" is a table alias, "*" is all-columns-wildcard (= select all columns from the table). I've updated my answer as you gave the details of your table data.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, i will put this as the answer when the website lets me. says i cannot accept an answer before 2 minutes.